# What does "jump" mean?

Tags: the-matrix

In *The Matrix Revolutions* (2003), Niobe surprised Roland's team, who are getting a full diagnostic on The Logos
ship:

> Niobe: You can put that shit away, boys. All she needs is a **jump**.

What does "jump" mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A '[jump start](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jump_start_(vehicle))' is where a battery source from a vehicle is used to start another one with a dead battery, e.g. using jumper cables to connect a good/charged car battery to the battery on a car with a drained battery.

Niobe is asking for Roland to use the Mjolnir's reactor to recharge the Logos.